# Clarification about precedence of operators

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I got this snippet from some exercises and the question: which is the output of following code:

```
main()
{
    char *p = "ayqm";
    printf("%c", ++*(p++));
}
```

My expected answer was `z` but the actual answer was in fact `b`. How is that possible?

Later edit: the snippet is taken as it is from an exercise and did not focus on the string literal or syntax issues existent in other than the `printf()` code zone.

Comment: moves pointer to address containing 'y', why?

Comment: Because that will help determine what an answer to the question should focus on. You response tells us there is some information you are lacking, now we know what it is.

Comment: But unfortunately, there is still a problem with your code, since you are modifying a string literal. The behavior is undefined. I can fix the example if you'd like, so that it doesn't derail the question.

Comment: `p++` incremements `p`, but has the value of the previous value of `p`, which points to the `a` in `"ayqm"`.  The `*` operator dereferences the pointer, giving the value `'a'`.  Then the `++` operator increments it, giving the result of `'a' + 1` which is `'b'`.  But note that `"ayqm"` is a constant string, and it is an error to attempt to modify it as this code does.  On some systems this would produce a segmentation fault (if the constant string is in read-only memory).

Comment: I think instead of searching for my lack of  information you could have written an one-line response with a hint, like many others would do.

Comment: I think your demonstrated attitude is undeserving of any help, tbh. I fixed some issues with your post, offered to resolve another fundamental one (that affects answers) to help answers stay on focus, and you act all defensive. You want your terrible post to be rightfully downvoted as low quality? Fine, I'll revert my edits.

Comment: I'm not here to hunt votes, I'm here to get help and to give help, if possible. Your attitude asking the first question instead of helping was kind of arrogant.

Comment: "Give help"? You haven't answered a single question in all of your time on SO. I believe you are here to get help however. Unfortunately SO is not a help-desk to replace a proper book on C for help vampires. The posts need to posses a quality of their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted, the program has multiple problems:

- it tries to modify the string constant `"ayqm"`, which described as *undefined behavior* in the C Standard.
- it uses `printf` without a proper declaration, again producing undefined behavior.
- its output is not terminated with a newline, causing implementation defined behavior.
- the prototype for `main` without a return type is obsolete, no longer supported by the C Standard.
- incrementing characters produces implementation defined behavior. If the execution character set is ASCII, `'a'+1` does produce `'b'`, but it is not guaranteed by the C Standard. Indeed in the EBCDIC character set still used in older mainframe computers letters are in a single monotonic sequence (ie: `'a'+1 == 'b'` but `'i'+1 != 'j'` in this character set).

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "ayqm";
    char *p = str;
    printf("%c\n", ++*(p++));
    return 0;
}
```

`p` is post-incremented, which means the current value of `p` is used for the `*` operator and the value of `p` is incremented before the next sequence point, namely the call to the `printf` function. The character read through `p`, `'a'` is then incremented, which may or may not produce `'b'` depending on the execution character set.

After `printf` returns to the `main` function, `p` points to `str[1]` and `str` contains the string `"byqm"`.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for; the associativity for postfx increment is a problem for me :)
The code is not meant to work, I suppose it was only the priintf() line of interest here.

Comment: @TeodorPetrut: it is a matter of operator precedence, not associativity. The rule for unary operators is simple: first posfix operators, starting with the one closest to the operand (left to right), then prefix operators also starting with the one closest to the operand (hence right to left). The result of prefix increment is the incremented value, whereas the result of postfix increment is the previous value. The side effect on the incremented object takes place at an unspecified time before the next sequence point.

Comment: @TeodorPetrut: Associativity determines the order of operation for binary operators. eg: `*` and `/` have the same precedence and left to right associativity, hence `a / b * c` is parsed and evaluated as `(a / b) * c`, whereas `=` has right to left associativity, so `a = b = c` is parsed as `a = (b = c)`. `a` may get a different value in `a = c` depending on the type of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is having undefined behavior because it is trying to modify the string literal "ayqm". As per the standard attempting to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior because it may be stored in read-only storage.

The pointer `p` is pointing to string literal "ayqm". This expression

```
printf ("%c", ++*(p++));
```

end up attempting to modify the string literal that pointer `p` is pointing to.

An undefined behavior in a program includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.